# What's the shooting algorithm for the mass-spring problem (ode)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

I have the following problem : 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d x(t)}{dt} &= y(t)\\
\frac{d y(t)}{dt} &= -x(t)+y(t)(1-x(t)^2)+u(t)
\end{aligned}
$$
with the initial condition $(x,y) = (0,0)$. Those equations represent the dynamic of the mass spring movement. I tried to find the optimal control in minimal time to stabilize the system close to (0,0).

The optimal control $u(t)$ I've found is in this case equal to $sign(p_y(t))$. Where $(p_x(t),p_y(t)$ is the function of the adjoint state.

I tried to apply and simulate the shooting algorithm on this problem but I had no idea what steps should I follow.

I will really appreciate any help of any kind on the use of the shooting algorithm.

Thank you in advance guys,

Comment: Did you mean the algorithm to do it? Single shooting, multiple shooting or something else? Regards

Comment: Thank you Amzoti
Just the single shooting algorithm.
Regards

Comment: Try these and see if they provide what you need (I may have a book reference at home and will check).

http://depts.washington.edu/amath/courses/301-autumn-2003/301lec15.pdf

http://www.tu-ilmenau.de/fileadmin/media/simulation/Lehre/div/Lec_Slides3.pdf (Slides 55 - end)

http://nm.mathforcollege.com/topics/shooting_method.html (see: http://mathforcollege.com/nm/mws/gen/08ode/mws_gen_ode_spe_shootingmethod.pdf)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method

Regards

Comment: Thank you so much Amzoti :)

Comment: You are quite welcome. Were you able to converge on your problem using those? Regards